# How do I render partial a block of code that has a JS function and a lot of references in body.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Hope I can phrase this question properly as I'm also getting a quite confused with partials. I have the following files:

> ./body.html.erb

> ./_sidebar.html.erb

Essentially, I'd like to paste all sidebar info into the body. It repeats itself quite a few times (in a few tabs) so I found a few resources saying that render partial is the correct way to re-call multiple blocks of code.

`./body.html.erb` looks like this: (essentially member_list returns data of users like username, image, etc as seen on the sidebar. It definitely has content in it and everything works when it is all within the `body.html.erb` file)

```
<div class="sidebar">
     <%= render partial: "sidebar", locals: { members: member_list } %>
</div>
```

`./_sidebar.html.erb` looks like this:

```
<div class="sidebar-content">
    <div class="sb-content-title">
            Members(<%= local_assigns[:members].count() %>)
    </div>
    <div class="member-list">
        <% local_assigns[:members].slice(0, 20).each do |user| %>
        <div class="member-img">
               <img width="46" height="46" src=<%= user.avatar_template.gsub('{size}', (46).to_s) %> class='avatar'>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are my questions:

1. What is causing my code not to work? Unfortunately I don't get any errors because of nginx (just the standard 500 error), but it works when I have the `sidebar-content` inside `body.html.erb` and replacing `local_assigns[:members]` to `member_list`.
2. How do I declare multiple variables to pass on? Would it be like so:

```
<%= render partial: "sidebar", locals: { members: member_list , members_check: members_exist} %>
```

3. How do I declare `openTab` in the locals of render partial if I adde the below code into the `_sidebar.html.erb`?

```
    <div class="see-members">
    <a onclick="openTab(event, 'Members')">see members <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right"></i> </a>
    </div>
```

### TLDR

#### This works (`body.html.erb`):

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-content">
        <div class="sb-content-title">
                Members(<%= member_list.count() %>)
        </div>
        <div class="member-list">
            <% member_list.slice(0, 20).each do |user| %>
            <div class="member-img">
                   <img width="46" height="46" src=<%= user.avatar_template.gsub('{size}', (46).to_s) %> class='avatar'>
            </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

#### This doesn't (when separated into 2 files):

`./body.html.erb`

```
<div class="sidebar">
     <%= render partial: "sidebar", locals: { members: member_list } %>
</div>
```

`./_sidebar.html.erb`:

```
<div class="sidebar-content">
    <div class="sb-content-title">
            Members(<%= local_assigns[:members].count() %>)
    </div>
    <div class="member-list">
        <% local_assigns[:members].slice(0, 20).each do |user| %>
        <div class="member-img">
               <img width="46" height="46" src=<%= user.avatar_template.gsub('{size}', (46).to_s) %> class='avatar'>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the variable of interest in the partial is `members` not `local_assigns[:members]`. When you render the partial does the variable `member_list` have a value? I can't tell, maybe it should be `@member_list`? Where is the value assigned? In the onClick handler, I don't believe the variable `event` has a value, leave it out.

Comment: Hi @LesNightingill , thanks for responding! Was following a different template, which was where I got `local_assigns[:members]`. I'll try just `members`. Yes, `member_list` always has a value. It is assigned within `body.html.erb`, it makes an API call. So in the onClick handler, is it safe to just enter in the `_sidebar.html.erb` file even though it's calling a JS function that's in `body.html.erb`?

Comment: Also would just like to add that the `_sidebar.html.erb` code works when I just combine it in `body.html.erb`, it's when it's separated and I attempt to render is when it doesn't work. So `member_list` definitely has value and works. Also not sure if it matters but both files are in the same directory

Comment: Just reporting back, I tried to start small and just return `Members(<%= members.count() %>)` from the `_sidebar.html.erb`, unfortunately it still doesn't work..

Comment: you don't need parens after `count`, but I don't think that's causing the problem. You need to prove to yourself that `member_list` is assigned a value which responds to the `.count` method. Just for testing put `<%= member_list.count %>` just before you render the partial... do you see it rendered?

Comment: When there is a 500 server error returned then the error message and the stack trace should be written into the application's log file. Please share the log entry for this problem. It is possible that the error is not related to how the variables are named but to how the partial is named and in what folder it is placed.

Comment: Hi @LesNightingill , when I run `Members(<%= members_list.count %>)`, I get: `Members (84)`

Comment: Thanks @spickermann, appreciate your response. I dug through and found this: `ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial landing_pages/landing/_sidebar with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby]}. Searched in:  * "/var/www/discourse/plugins/discourse-landing-pages/app/views"
  * "/var/www/discourse/plugins/discourse-calendar/app/views"
  * "/var/www/discourse/app/views"
  * "/var/www/discourse/plugins/docker_manager/app/views"
  * "/var/www/discourse/plugins/discourse-docs/app/views"`

Comment: @spickermann, I think this solves it, I might just have to make sure the `_sidebar.html.erb` is within one of those directories, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby on Rails will always look in the current controller's view folder for a partial unless the partial name is prefixed with another folder name.

The [official Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) suggest placing shared partials in `app/views/shared` and then specifying that path when including the partial.

Place the partial at `app/views/shared/_sidebar.html.erb` and change the call in the body to this:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <%= render partial: "shared/sidebar", locals: { members: member_list } %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @spickermann , I found the logs and you're right, I need to move the file to the proper folder. Thank you!